# How to work with utf-8 string in C (visual studio)

Tags: c, visual-studio, encoding

According to [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130(v=vs.85).aspx)

> For the most consistent results, applications should use Unicode, such
>   as UTF-8 or UTF-16, instead of a specific code page

I know that Window use utf-16 by default in the form of wchar_t, but how can I convert those wchar_t into multibyte (utf-8) without codepage?
Let's say I have data stored in utf-8 files, The only way I know of to process these files is to open with `fopen(fn, "r,ccs=utf-8")` and read the text into a wchar_t pointer which is utf-16 but I want to use utf-8 only. So I have to convert it with `wcstombs` or `WideCharToMultiByte` which depends on the codepage (and do not work all the time because of the codepage). 
Is there any workaround? like read directly utf-8 files into utf-8 `char*` variable?

Comment: Well you can read them *without* specifying an encoding when opening the file...

Comment: You probably shouldn't work with multibyte characters strings. Why not simply work with wide char strings?

Comment: @Medinoc wouldn't it make me clueless about what I am reading? For example what would `fgetc()` return?

Comment: @MichaelWalz Yeah my program works fine with wchar, however now we need to deploy the code in other platform, e.g android, and it turns out we should use utf-8 for consistency

Comment: @AtheS21 As far as I know, in "dumb" mode fgetc() would return each byte separately, therefore you'd need N calls for a N-byte character. And as UTF-8 is specified, the first byte of each character tells you how many bytes are needed.

Comment: @Medinoc that's what I think, then I have to decode utf-8 by myself, I would rather avoid that

Comment: @AtheS21 the only way Windows will decode UTF-8 for you is the built-in conversion to UTF-16. There's no built-in way to get directly UTF-32 code points from UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WideCharToMultibyte](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130.aspx) for this conversion, passing in `CP_UTF8` for the CodePage argument.

Comment: There was a comment saying OP does not want to send multibyte chars to an Arduino. I don’t know why it disappeared (did I fat finger?), but it appears the Windows API’s definition of multibyte strings here is fairly broad (ha!). Specifically: _The new character string is not necessarily from a multibyte character set._ In any case, UTF-8 is one of the options.